# What feminine products will become commonplace for men in the future?

Tags: society, science-in-society, gender

I think it is totally unfair that there are clothes and products for men and women. I believe it is possible to create feminine products for guys and many brands will create in the future.

Exemples:

Makeup;

Skirts;

Dresses;

-All feminine clothes;

-Bras for guys with manboobs and get awkward to show them;

-Jewelry;

-Lingerie.

I'd love to write a sci fi story which gender roles have disappeared(I think they are silly and nonsense)in the future and thus most gendered products has become obsolete. But I don't have enough time to create it.

People say that men and women wear different clothes because of different in body shape but that does not make sense since all body shapes exist in both sexes and there are men with manboobs, which could benefit from a bra.

Comment: The female shaving razors are actually pretty good. I know a guy who exclusively uses those to shave his beard and is very happy with the results.

Comment: Hmmm. Welcome. Please take have a look at the [tour] and [help] if you haven't already. The impression I get with this question is essentially "I don't have time to come up with a solution, please do the work for me?". Entire books can be written exploring this question and all depend of the story circumstances. How would you consider one answer more valid than another? I mean if I answer based of a dystopia 50 years in the future, or 100 years from now after the discovery of advanced alien life, which answer would be more/less incorrect/correct based off the information you have supplied.

Comment: Many of these things exist as unisex products, several others have gendered equivalents, and all can be found at a Pride parade.  Regardless of whether you define "men" by sex, gender, or something else, you can easily find examples of mean who wear jewelry, makeup, skirts (kilts or otherwise), "feminine" clothing, lingerie, and bras.

Comment: Well, it's a bit tough to predict the future.... but if history is anything to go by, the first skirts were thought to have been Egyptian and were of course worn almost exclusively by men, notably Roman soldiers wore something akin to mini-skirts. Make-up has always been worn by men in certain circles and with fashion trends like "goth". I commonly see jewellery on men ( see Mr T or"medallion man" for iconic examples), much of it religious in nature. Lingerie, I can tell you a lady's thong is phenomenally uncomfortable and quite impractical in men so that one's out. Fashion changes.

Comment: On a personal note, I'd been wondering about a sports bra for men for a while to prevent chaffing on exercising, but no one seems to make those yet, so sticky plasters might have to do, but this is not a chat site, so I'll shut up now.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that comes and goes with time. Remember that in ancient Greece everybody dressed about the same. And in ancient Egypt, it was commonplace for men to use makeup as much as women did.

As for men wearing jewelry, look at any famous rapper nowadays. Those guys are more adorned than a Christmas tree.

And as for skirts, there is nothing more manly than wearing one if it is pleated and made in Scotland.

It all boils down to culture, so if you say in your story that that's how it is, then that's how it is. [Star Trek has had men wearing dresses and skirts for a long while](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11357/33542). You can see it right at the very first minutes of the first episode of *Star Trek: The New Generation* (if you have Netflix, check the 14:30 mark). Exploring gender roles in much more depth and liberal ways has also been done extensively in seminal works of sci-fi such as The Forever War, The Left Hand of Darkness and so many other great books.